# Django Abandoned/Unused Models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a models.py file with 6-10 unused models on a Django Project.
What do you do with these unused models? Do you delete them (and migrate them out)? Do you just push them to the side and ignore them?

Comment: If they are unused and data won't be ever again needed, then yeah, I'm deleting models and making new migrations to delete them from DB

Comment: after I delete models I ./manage.py remove_stale_contenttypes